# Solvability Helmholtz equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $D=D_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda>0$.
Consider the Helmholtz operator $L=(\Delta +\lambda I).$

Let $f\in Ker_0(L)$, that is $f$ solves
$$ Lf=0\quad\text{ in $D$}, $$
$$ f=0\quad\text{ on $\partial D$}.$$

Consider, for a given boundary datum $g$, the problem
$$ Lu=f\quad\text{ in $D$},$$
$$ u=g\quad\text{ on $\partial D$}. $$

Are there necessary and sufficient conditions for the solvability of this problem?
If so, which would be the correct formulation in terms of function spaces?

Comment: Try integrate $\|f\|_{L^2}=\int fLu$ by parts.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000001591/3_VuChapter3.pdf;jsessionid=F6A9E06042E569A3BD7A0421DDF6C097?hosts=) related.

Comment: This might be useful. Where can I find the references cited in this PDF?

Answer (score 0):

One necessary condition follows from integration by parts:

$$ \int_D f^2=\int_D fLu=\int_{\partial D} (f\partial_nu-u\partial_nf)+\int_D uLf=\int_{\partial D} g\partial_nf. $$